# Matlab - Warning: popupmenu control requires a non-empty String

Tags: matlab

I know that this error is caused when a popupmenu initializes with an empty list, but I have several popupmenu, how to know the tag of popupmenu that generates me this error?
Or there is way to stop generate this warning?

Thanks

Comment: It's a warning, not an error, right? have a look at [how to suppress warnings](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/suppress-warnings.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a structured array such as `handles` with the use of MATLAB's GUIDE or your own structured array, this could work by finding the double value of the components handle and matching that to the fieldnames in the structure by calling your structure in the script or command line (depending upon work-space).

```
components = findall(figure_handle,'Style','Popupmenu'); % returns double value for each handle
menu_strings = get(components,'String'); % gets the string of each popupmenu
indx = find(strcmpi(menu_strings,'')); % returns the position in the array of the empty components
wanted_components = components(indx) % returns the double value of the components that have an empty string
```

Also, you can use the `Tag` property and If you had tags set you could then add:

```
get(wanted_components,'Tag')
```

See documentation for [find all](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findall.html) and [tag property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol_props.html#bqxoiq2).